# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException Error while writting query in visual basic

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\BlackHat\Documents\Travel.accdb")
        Dim qry As String = "update Login set UserName='" & TextBox1.Text & "',Password='" & TextBox2.Text & "' where ID=" & Val(TextBox3.Text)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(qry, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox(qry)
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Following error occurred in the query. the syntax and variable looks fine.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
> Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Comment: Which database server you are using?

Comment: debug the content of qry to see what are you sending to db. The code looks ok, so maybe there is some single quote `'` in the textbox. And be aware your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use parameters.

Comment: i  got it .
it was happening because one column was "Password" i renamed it and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim qry As String ="update Login set UserName='" & TextBox1.Text & "',Password='" & TextBox2.Text & "' where ID=" & Val(TextBox3.Text) & ""
```